# Получение полного пути с атрибутами

Tags: php, .htaccess

Т.е. собственно пишу, что то типа не до анонимайзера, 
Есть сайт, на нем разные страницы:

```
test.ru/kek
test.ru/kek88/rikki/slow/blob/
test.ru/kek/rofler/?hh=14
test.ru/kek/124452
```

Задача парсить все что идет после первого слеша и  отправлять на index.php.

Собственно мной она решилась так:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_\/\=\?\+]+)$ ?id=$1 [L]
```

Но при этом не парсится

```
test.ru/kek/rofler/?hh=14
test.ru/kek/rofler/?hh=14&dsf=g%gsdfsg
```

Как я понял, моя проблема в регулярке, помогите её подправить, что бы она кушала все символы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно наоборот не дописывать ничего к адресу:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
```

Затем вся исходная строка запроса будет в переменной:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Дальше вы её проксируете как удобно:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://example.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
```

Если нужно удалить какую-то часть строки запроса, то это тоже легко делается прямо в PHP.